# Debug and test on Javascript console for a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, debugging, debug, chrome

I recently saw a UI/UX guy debug on JavaScript console in Chrome. I too have worked on this console but I would like to ask this simple question. When I create something like this on VF...

```
<tr>
  <td><apex:outputLabel value="Test" for="test"/> </td>  
</tr>
```

Instead of making changes on VF, I would like to make changes on the HTML generated on right clicking and **inspect**.

What I have tried so far...

I tried to add this on the inspect window--> **Edit as HTML**.

```
<tr>
  <td style="width: 50px;"><apex:outputLabel value="Test" for="test"/> </td> 
</tr>
```

But I could see no temporary changes on the VF. What is the proper way to test and use Javascript console in Chrome?

Let me know if I was able to convey my thoughts properly.

Comment: Not really on topic here. But you can open the developer tools. Highlight the elements and edit them directly. Sometimes it does not take the first time so do it again. To execute JS goto the Console tab and you can directly execute your JS from there.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have written vf code `<apex:outputLabel value="Test" for="test"/>` in developer tool. May be it is a typo error. Only HTML/JS is supported in developer tool.

You can edit the generated html in developer tool as below. In Screen 2 I have added the style tag `style="width: 100px;"` and you can see the effect (more gap betwwen Test and textbox) in the page instantly. But remember this is a temporary change, if you refresh the page the changes will be lost. If you satisfy with the changes, you have to add those in vf page to retain permanently.

Screen 1[image]

Screen 2
[image]

Comment: Thanks @saroj-bera. Thanks for explaining with screenshots!

Comment: If it's helped you, please mark it as answer.